# Setting state value coming from axios when using useState() and useEffect() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-testing-library

When I run this test the axios call is mocked correctly but `setParticipant()` never sets the value of the `participant` variable. I'm guessing it's because it's asynchronous. How do I "wait" for the `setParticipant()` call to complete before asserting in the test?

participant.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function EditParticipant(props) {
  const [participant, setParticipant] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`/api/participants`).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)        // prints fine
        setParticipant(response.data)
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {participant ?   // always null
        <p>{participant.name}</p>           
        : ''
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

participant-spec.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import { EditParticipant } from './participant-edit';

const mock = new MockAdapter(require('axios'));

describe('<Participant/>', () => {
  let container
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
  });

  it('show bob', async () => {
    mock.onGet("/api/participants").reply(200, {name: "bob" });
    act(() => {
      render(<EditParticipant />, container);
    });
    expect(container.textContent).toContain("Bob")
  });
});
```

Comment: In the example I had taken out `props.participantId` to simplify it. It's gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using async hooks try adding `await` in front of `act` to apply resolved promises:

```
it('show bob', async () => {
  mock.onPost("/api/participants").reply(200, {name: "bob" });
  await act(async () => {
    render(<EditParticipant />, container);
  });
  expect(container.textContent).toContain("Bob")
});
```

This is covered briefly in the [data fetching](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching) portion of the testings recipes documentation.

Hopefully that helps!